# Separating Column Based on First Value of String

Tags: r, string, startswith

I have an ID variable that I am trying to separate into two separate columns based on their prefix being either a 1 or 2.

An example of my data is:

```
STR_ID
1434233
2343535
1243435
1434355
```

I have tried countless ways to try to separate these variables into columns based on their prefixes, but cannot seem to figure it out. Any ideas on how I would do this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you post a desired output?

Comment: I don't understand why you change to a single string with `toString`

Comment: that must be my issue, I thought I was changing each individual variable to a string. Would you know the syntax for changing variable types to string?

Answer (score 2):

We create a grouping variable with `substr` by extracting the first character/digit of 'STR_ID', and `spread` it to 'wide' format

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(grp = paste0('grp', substr(STR_ID, 1, 1))) %>% 
   mutate(i = row_number()) %>% 
   spread(grp, STR_ID) %>%
   select(-i)
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#     grp1    grp2
#    <int>   <int>
#1 1434233 2343535
#2 1243435      NA
#3 1434355      NA
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(STR_ID = c(1434233L, 2343535L, 1243435L, 1434355L
 )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: Sorry I couldn't test this until now, but I am getting the error: Error in group_by_(.data, .dots = compat_as_lazy_dots(...), add = add) : 
  argument ".data" is missing, with no default

Comment: @statuser  It is based on the data showed.  I updated with the dataset used.  It is working for me

Comment: that is just a small sample of my data; this is a dataset with around 50 million observations. Would I still use the same code structure? Thank you for your time.

Comment: @statuser if the structure is the same, it should work.  If it is not then, you have to show an example that mimics the full data

Comment: the structure of the data is the same, but it is simply stored in the variable STR_ID and without a data frame that lists all of the values.

Comment: I updated my data section, which is what I have instead of the df1. Wouldn't this change the code?

Comment: @statuser If you data name is `df2`, it should be `df2 %>% group_by`